# Multi Select List Box Document Property with Search bar enabled

Tags: spotfire

I am working on Multi Select List Box document property with search field.

It works fine when I give any keyword like 'An' it gives me Andorra, Angola, Anguilla etc. I can multi-select all these 3 records and make my underlying data table filtered.

Now the challenge is, if I search for the records that starts with Z in the search bar and click Enter then the above selection is deselected/disappeared (meaning the last search elements alone will be available).

Any ideas on how to make the current selection and newly searched elements available ?

Any inputs and suggestions would be much helpful.

Attached the sample dxp file and screenshots.[image]

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to ask your users to hold the "ctrl" key ? It would be much more simple.

Comment: @txemsukr: Thanks for the response. That is feasible if the record count is less than 1000. In my original dashboard there are nearly 10,000 unique values and spotfire restricts the multi select list box to 1000 (meaning only first 1000 unique values are displayed in the list box). I am looking for a way to achieve it through search option.  Is there any way to achieve this?
Note: I can't use Insert Filter option as well in my dashbord due to other requirements.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the filtering you are doing is based on the document property attached to this multi select list box.
You can make another property and attach this value to that doc property, whenever somebody changes this value run an IronPython to append to that doc property.
Give a reset button to clear this value when required